# event.keyCode doesn't work for enter key

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've read that the enter keycode should be 13.  However when using

```
trace(event.keyCode);
```

other keys will show up but the enter key does not.  Could it be my computer or something? Using macbook pro keyboard.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, entered);

function entered(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace(event.keyCode);
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER){
    //or if (event.keyCode == 13){
        trace("enter button");
    }
}
```

i.e. I can't get this to trace "enter button"
Also noticed no code traceable for Ctrl. alt Tab or Backpace

Comment: try disable the js in your page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I believe noone here really tried it ^^.

My guess: you're running this via run movie (Cmd+Return) command. If my guess is right, in Flash Application Bar (while your application is running) go into Commands->Disable Keyboard shortcuts.

^^

What's happening: Flash player (or fpdebug) has some keyboard shortcuts, which, if pressed, act as keyboard shortcuts for flash and do not reach your movie. Enter is shortcut for 'Play Movie'.

Answer (score 2):

Are you compiling this in Flash?
If so, this is, probably, the problem...

Flash Debug Player intercepts some key presses.
To get rid of it, check "Disable keyboard shortcuts" in Controls menu of the player.

My Flash is in Portuguese, but you should find it easily.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the first trace show "13" when you press the enter key? Or doesn't pressing ENTER trigger any traces?

I used pretty much the same code in a project of mine, the only difference is that I listen for KEY_UP instead of KEY_DOWN. Does that make a difference?

There's another possibility: maybe some other object listens for KEY_DOWN Events from the stage too, and prevents those Events from propagating to your event listener.

Comment: No there is nothing from even the first trace, and KEY_UP does the same.

Comment: Then what about the other possibility: do you have any other classes that have KeyboardEvent listeners?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a focus problem, with another application receiving the enter keypresses instead of Flash. Are you running this in a browser or the standalone player?